# velocity of joint in pin-jointed mechanism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I've the following problem:
Given the speeds $V_a$ and $V_b$ of the sliders A and B, from the mechanism given on the picture, find the speed of C
Picture:
[image]

A note before I give the solution:
There is a theorem which I don't know how it's named in English. It states that the projections of two forces, laying on the same line are equal and have the same direction.The theorem name translated literally is theory for projecting forces

$V_a * cos\alpha = V_b * cos\beta$

Now the following solution is given: 
Since the C connects the two pristons rod(not sure if this is the name in English), $AC$ and $BC$, the point C belongs to both of them. According to the theorem for projecting forces we have:
proj of $V_A$ on $AC$ = proj of $V_C$ on $AC$ 
 
proj of $V_B$ on $BC$ = proj of $V_C$ on $BC$ 
We find the projection of $V_A$ on $AC$,  $a$. Then we build segment $CC1$ = $a$, after that we are repeating the process for $V_B$, and build segment $CC2$ = $b$. From the points $C1$ and $C2$ we raise perpendiculars, to $BC$ and $AC$, the intersection point of those perpendiculars is the end of the force $V_c$.

There are a lot of problems with the solution. However I managed to solve most of those. However I can't understand why the intersection point of the perpendiculars is the end of the force $V_c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because with that method you find the projection of the velocity (what you called force is actually called velocity) in the two directions, so the velocity of C is the vector with those projections, for this reason you take the intersection of the perpendicular lines, you can see indeed that you fin a vector whose projections in the directions of the rod are the speed you calculated.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the idea behind the fact that if I have two project, and I draw perpendiculars from them, their intersection point will be the end of the vector. Could you give me a term to search, or tutorial on this topic. I will be really grateful.

Comment: You do the same thing in the first step of the exercise, to find the projection of Va you draw the perpendicular line to a that arrives in Va. All the vectors with a particular projection lie in the perpendicular line to the projection, so if you what  to find the vector that is the projection of two other vectors, it must lie on the perpendicular line of both, so it must lie on their intersection.